# Magento core controller extend query

Tags: php, magento

what happens when 2 different modules override a same function , which one will govern the behavior
ex-  I have extended CartController class where i have defined a new deleteAction function, what if another module also has same deletefunction

Comment: You should consider using an event if possible instead of overriding. https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-9/

Comment: I very much doubt you will find many extensions that override a controller. That is considered a last resort in Magento and it doesn’t provide a neat way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP autoloader priority (include_path)

It tries in this order:

```
./app/code/local
./app/code/community
./app/code/core
```

So anything defined in local will override community, regardless of any internal Magento rewrites.

Comment: yeah i know that, but what if  both modules are in local folder

Comment: either change the other extension to extend yours. Or, remove the rewrite from the other extension config.xml,